# Generate messages in Omnet++ from source node and receive acknowledgement from the receiver node

Tags: c++, eclipse, omnet++, packet

I am trying to do an Omnet++ simulation in which there are three nodes **Node1**, **Node2** and **Node3**. These are connected as - **Node1**-->**Node2**-->**Node3**.

**Node1** is the source node and generates packets at the rate of 50 packets/sec. **Node2** simply forwards the packets to **Node3**. And **Node3** deletes all the packets, and for every tenth packet received by **Node3** it sends an acknowledgement to **Node1**.

For now I could only send packets from **Node1** to **Node3**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

class communicate : public cSimpleModule
{ private:
    cMessage *event;
    cMessage *tictocMsg;

  protected:
    virtual void forwardMessage(cMessage *msg);
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
    virtual cMessage *generateMessage();
};

Define_Module(communicate);

void communicate::initialize()
{
    if (getIndex() == 0) {
        // Boot the process scheduling the initial message as a self-message.
        char msgname[20];
        sprintf(msgname, "Node-%d", getIndex());
        cMessage *msg = new cMessage(msgname);
        scheduleAt(0.0, msg);
    }
}

void communicate::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    if (getIndex() == 2) {
        // Message arrived.

        EV << "Message " << msg << " arrived.\n";
        delete msg;
        initialize();

    }
    else {
        // We need to forward the message.
        forwardMessage(msg);

}

void communicate::forwardMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    // In this example, we just pick a random gate to send it on.
    // We draw a random number between 0 and the size of gate `out[]'.
    int n = gateSize("out");
    int k = intuniform(0, n-1);

    EV << "Forwarding message " << msg << " on port out[" << k << "]\n";
    send(msg, "out", k);
}
```

**.ned file**

```
simple communicate
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=block/routing");
    gates:
        input in[];  // declare in[] and out[] to be vector gates
        output out[];
}

network fournodes
{   
    submodules:
        Node[2]: communicate;
    connections:
        Node[0].out++ --> {  delay = 10ms; } --> Node[1].in++;
        
        Node[1].out++ --> {  delay = 10ms; } --> Node[2].in++;
}
```

Please tell if there is any way forward from this code such that it solves the given problem. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add NED file of your network?

Comment: @JerzyD. Thanks. I have edited the question and added the .ned file.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have declared two nodes instead of three. In NED file it should be:

   ```
   submodules:
      Node[3]: communicate;  // here 3 is the number of nodes
   ```
2. There is no connection from Node[2] to Node[1] nor from Node[1] to Node[0]. You should add:

   ```
    Node[2].out++ --> {  delay = 10ms; } --> Node[1].in++;
    Node[1].out++ --> {  delay = 10ms; } --> Node[0].in++;
   ```
3. In order to generate 50 messages in 1 sec one should send a selfmessage every 0.02 s. The sample code:

   ```
   // inside declaration of class communicate
   cMessage * timer;

   // in initialize():
   timer = new cMessage();
   scheduleAt(0.0, timer);

   // in handleMessage(cMessage *msg):
   if (msg == timer) {
      // generate and send message
      // ...
      // scheduling next sending in 20 ms
      scheduleAt(simTime() + 0.02, timer);

   } else {
      // old code, i.e.
      if (getIndex() == 2) {
        // ...
   ```

}

Comment: Thanks. I suppose the two way connections are required for receiving the acknowledgement? My bad I missed it. Can you please address the rest of the problem as well like generating 50 packets/sec and also receiving the acknowledgement?

Comment: I extended my answer by adding some clues how to send several messages. According acknowledgement: could you precise what should be the difference between "regular" message and ACK message?

Comment: Isn't better to use bidirectional communication in this case? https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part4/#43-using-two-way-connections

Comment: @eugene: it depends - using bidirectional connection simplifies the NED. However, in that case in the code the suffix "$o" must be used to indicate the output part of a gate, i.e. something like that has to be used `send(msg, "out$o", k)`.

Comment: @JerzyD. Thanks. The acknowledgement message can be assumed as a string for example "ack received".

Comment: @JerzyD. I am not able to understand why the simulation runs only for one iteration. Please check wether it's running for you.

Comment: @Fitzgerald Brooks: in the code presented in your question only one message is scheduled. Moreover, that message is deleted after reaching Node 3.

Comment: @JerzyD. I also tried what you have suggested in your answer, but the same thing is happening. The packet generated by the source node is getting deleted at the destination node and the simulation ends.

Comment: @Fitzgerald Brooks: I suggest creating a new question with the code you have tried as well as with the description of the problem.

Comment: @JerzyD. Can I edit the same question with the code that I have tried?

Comment: @Fitzgerald Brooks: No, you should not edit this question., because the answer may become incomprehensible.

Comment: @JerzyD. I have posted a new question-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855035/omnet-generate-packets-from-the-source-node-and-receive-acknowledgement-pack