# Omnet++ : Generate packets from the source node and receive acknowledgement packet from the destination node

Tags: c++, eclipse, omnet++

Three nodes **Node1**, **Node2** and **Node3** are connected in point to point fashion as - **Node1**-->**Node2**-->**Node3**.

**Node1** is the source node and generates packets at the rate of 50 packets/sec. **Node2** simply forwards the packets to **Node3** which is the destination node. And **Node3** deletes all the packets, and for every tenth packet received by **Node3** it sends an acknowledgement packet back to **Node1**.

I have written the following code for the given problem setup-

**.cc file**

```
class communicate : public cSimpleModule
{ public:
    cMessage *timer;
    cMessage *data;

  protected:
    virtual void forwardMessage(cMessage *msg);
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;};

Define_Module(communicate);

void communicate::initialize()
{
    if (getIndex() == 0) {
        timer=new cMessage();
        scheduleAt(0.0, timer);
    }
}

void communicate::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{   int count=0;

    if (msg == timer){

            data=new cMessage("hello");
            EV<<"NEW PACKET GENERATED  getIndex()\n";
            forwardMessage(data);
            scheduleAt(simTime()+0.01, timer);
        }

    else {
            if(getIndex()==1)
            {
                forwardMessage(data);
            }

            else
            {
                EV<<"MESSAGE ARRIVED AT DESTINATION\n";
                delete data;
            }
         }
}

void communicate::forwardMessage(cMessage *msg)
{   if(getIndex()==0)
    {
    send(msg,"out1");
    }
    else(getIndex()==1)
    {
     send(msg,"out2");
    }
}
```

and the corresponding **.ned file**-

```
simple communicate
{
    parameters:

        @display("i=block/routing");
    gates:
        input in1;
        input in2;  
        output out1;
        output out2;
}

network fournodes
{
    @display("bgb=130,142");
    submodules:
        tic[3]: communicate;
    connections:
        tic[0].out1 --> {  delay = 1ms; } --> tic[1].in1;
        tic[1].out1 --> {  delay = 1ms; } --> tic[0].in1;

        tic[1].out2 --> {  delay = 1ms; } --> tic[2].in1;
        tic[2].out1 --> {  delay = 1ms; } --> tic[1].in2;
}
```

For the above written code, I am getting the following error after execution--

```
send()/sendDelayed(): Message pointer is nullptr -- in module (communicate) fournodes.tic[1] (id=3), at t=0.001s, event #2
```

Please point out the mistake that I have made in this code or suggest some alternate way to solve the problem. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The presented code generates the error "Gate index 2 out of range", because in the line `send(msg, "out", n+1);` index of a gate is too big.

Comment: @JerzyD. can you suggest what else I can write since the packet needs to be transferred to the next hop node?

Comment: @JerzyD. can you please check my updated code in the question? For now I have removed the part of sending acknowledgement packet to the source node.

Comment: When `tic[1]` receives any message, `handleMessage()` is called. In that case the condition `getIndex()==1` is equal to true, therefore `forwardMessage(data)` is called. But `data` is null pointer, because `data` is generated only for the node for which `getIndex()==0`. That explains your runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should precise how the node that receives a message determines whether and where forward that message. In `tictocMsg` you have declared `source` and `destination` but these fields are not checked anywhere.
I suggest assuming some rules for "routing" messages in the network. For example, it may be assumed that:

1. Every node has own Address (e.g. tic[0] - has address 0, tic[1] - 1, etc.).
2. Every node has a static "routing" table. The table is filled in advance. For example, the table for `tic[1]` may look like:

| Destination address | Index of `out` gate |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 |

3. When the node receives a message, it checks whether `destination` from this message is equal to own address. If no - message is forwarded via the gate selected from the table. If yes - message is processed locally.

Comment: I am not able to understand how to make my code functionable. Can you please make changes to my code or suggest some better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you describe how a node should know which gate should be used to forward a message to tic[2]? You didn't mention that in your question nor in the code.

Comment: I have tried to make my code a little bit simpler. I did include the 2 input output gates as suggested by you. Still I am encountering some error which I am unable to resolve. Can you please take a look into my new code.

Comment: We use simulation to verify some idea of communication. Unfortunately, you did not present your way of routing, so it is difficult to decide whether your code is in line with your idea. Could you write (as text) the rules of forwarding messages? For example:  1. Every node checks `destination` in received message. 2. `tic[0]` sends messages with `destiantion=1` via `out2`, with `destination=2` - via `out10`, etc. ....